# Parsing a drupal web page to get individual elements in android?

Tags: android, drupal, web, webview, web-applications

I am trying to create an android app that is a mobile site type app, similar to the way the Facebook app is. The app is a mobile version of a single page on a website, this web page is a search engine for the site. you type in a key word and it finds all of the products on that site with that key word, and displays them in drupal View. The problem with creating a mobile site, is that I still have all of the features of the site to worry about, which I don't want in the app. What I want in the app is a single search box that allows me to search for the product name, and displays *only* the list of products (not the sidebars, the menus, or anything else on the site. similar to the way that the facebook app doesn't display everything on it's mobile site, but is able to customize the layout of everything) How can I isolate the individual elements so that I can put them individually into a layout on the android application and display them as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not control the server, then you should download and parse html with A html parser such as JSOUP and extract elements that are of your interest. Note that this can break in the future if structure or URL of the page changes.

If you do control the server, then you should just provide data in JSON format and parse that with a JSON parser of your choice (mine is GSON).

Comment: can JSOUP parse for images, videos and sound files too?